# Should i be more specific with column names when using the EAV pattern

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Should I be more specific with column names when using the EAV pattern?

I have a custom form builder application where users can choose from a set of specific field types (textbox, textarea, email, URL, integer, decimal, date etc). It's a similar idea to formstack and surveymonkey.

I have decided to use the EAV approach to store values the user enters into these form fields,  what I want to know is if the columns in the database should be generic or specific? e.g.

**Generic**

> FormValuesTable
>   - Id
>   - UserId
>   - QuestionId
>   - **TextValue  (Type NVARCHAR)** - will hold textbox, textarea, email and URL values
>   - IntegerValue  (Type Integer)
>   - DecimalValue  (Type Decimal)
>   - DateValue  (Type DateTime)

**Specific**

> FormValuesTable
>   - Id
>   - UserId
>   - QuestionId
>   - **TextboxValue (Type NVARCHAR)**
>   - **TextAreaValue (Type NVARCHAR)**
>   - **EmailValue (Type NVARCHAR)**
>   - **URLValue (Type NVARCHAR)**
>   - IntegerValue  (Type Integer)
>   - DecimalValue  (Type Decimal)
>   - DateValue  (Type DateTime)

I also have a question table which holds the type of field (textbox, textarea, email, URL, integer, decimal, date).

The advantage of having a Generic table is that it will mean less columns, and the advantage of having a Specific table is that it makes more domain sense.

Comment: Technically, eav is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Having specific names for something that is meant to be completely generic does not seem to make much sense to me.